# How can I solve $y''=\frac{a}{y^2}$ where a is a (positive) constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, physics

Actually, I found out a way to solve that, but I can't get rid of complex numbers. And it does not make sense when it comes to complex numbers as the original question that involves this differential equation has nothing to do with complex numbers, as this is from a physics question.

Comment: Could you show the solution with complex numbers you've already found? It'll be easier to see if there's a way to un-complexify it if we know what it is.

Comment: $y=(\sqrt{-4.5at^2}+c)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ As a is a positive constant, the thing inside the bracket is always complex number...

Comment: x @KHC, how about substituting $u=-y$ first? Then move the sign from $y''=-u''$ to the other side, and then you have the original equation back with a negative $a$ instead.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I've never thought of that... Thank you!

Comment: But now when I substitute when t=0, y must be some number which is $-c^{\frac{2}{3}}$, but if this number is a positive number, I still get back complex number:(

Answer (score 7):

HINT:

$$y''(t)=\frac{a}{y(t)^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y''(t)y'(t)=\frac{ay'(t)}{y(t)^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int y''(t)y'(t)\space\text{d}t=\int\frac{ay'(t)}{y(t)^2}\space\text{d}t\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{y'(t)^2}{2}=\text{C}_1-\frac{a}{y(t)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(t)^2=2\text{C}_1-\frac{2a}{y(t)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(t)=\pm\sqrt{\text{C}_1-\frac{2a}{y(t)}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{y'(t)}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1-\frac{2a}{y(t)}}}=\pm1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{y'(t)}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1-\frac{2a}{y(t)}}}\space\text{d}t=\int\pm1\space\text{d}t\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{y'(t)}{\sqrt{\frac{\text{C}y(t)-2a}{y(t)}}}\space\text{d}t=\text{C}_2\pm t$$

Now, for the integral you can substitute $u=\text{C}y(t)-2a$ and $\text{d}u=\text{C}y'(t)\space\text{d}t$.

We get:

$$\int\frac{y'(t)}{\sqrt{\frac{\text{C}y(t)-2a}{y(t)}}}\space\text{d}t=\frac{1}{\text{C}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\text{C}u}{u+2a}}}\space\text{d}u$$

Comment: Thank you, so then I need to use integration by parts? The integral I get is too complicated and quite not useful in finding the u, which helps in finding y(t).

Comment: @KHCheung You're welcome I'm glad that I could help you. For the integration with respect to $u$ you don't have to use integration by parts, you can use again a substitution $s=u+2a$ and $\text{d}s=\text{d}u$